# Proxy API browser extension - detect when extension run in firefox or chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

I've read the documentation about proxy api for chrome extensions and for firefox and their implementation is different. Since I don't want to write different code for each browser, is there any possibility to use the `browser` namespace or to have only one codebase by detecting when an extension is running on chrome or in firefox so I can run form the background script the right code for the proxy API?

Comment: See also https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill

Comment: @wOxxOm Polyfill it's already bundled into the vue cli plugin I'm using to make the extension boilerplate. The problem is that the two proxy api are different and I can't write the code for chrome using browser namespace because it will not work in firefox also with polyfill.

Comment: As you can see in the linked topic, you can detect via `chrome.app`. Another method is to check `if (chrome.proxy.register)` as it's present only in Firefox.

Comment: firefox didn't use anymore  the register method, it's deprecated.

Comment: So do you need help with something else?